# Three children get trapped in a painting, inside a maze in a building

Tags: story-identification

There are three children. They are in some sort of building where there is a painting. There is some sort of maze in the building and one of the children walks through the maze, chanting a particular word. The other two children soon realise that he is missing and imitate what he did before he went missing. The two children find themselves in the painting and they have to find their friend who entered the painting earlier than them. All the people they meet in the painting are unable to move or talk, with a few exceptions. They soon manage to escape from the painting.

Comment: This sounds vaguely familiar. I don't remember the maze/chanting part, but I remember reading a book where some kids get stuck in the world of a painting, and all the people in it can only do certain things (the same things they are doing in the painting). But in the background of the world (what the painting doesn't show) there is quite a bit going on. Sound familiar, or am I thinking of something else?

Comment: Did the three children go to a strict art school? i remember a scene where the three children decided to make dodgy landscape in the attic in secret and did some crazy magic to enter the paint

Answer (score 2):

Might be "Dragon Magic" by Andre Norton, it was a puzzle, not a painting, but sounds a bit similar. Four kids, four adventures, they have to cooperate to get out. http://charlotteslibrary.blogspot.com/2013/04/dragon-magic-by-andre-norton-for.html

Answer (score 1):

This bothered me for so long, but I think this what you were looking for, it was called *[Artscape](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0212644/)*.

> When two children are touring an art gallery with the aide of a handheld speaker guide, the guide comes to life and takes them to another world called Artscape to teach them about the basics of art in more detail. Soon, the kids and the guide are separated and the kids must explore their world and people in it to find their way home, and along the way, they learn more about the visual arts than they ever dreamed possible.

Comment: Was there a maze or a fire?